# WPF ResourceDictionary not found in Excel 2013 Plugin

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

I have some code that has been running in a Visual Studio plugin project without issues. We are now porting some of the functionality to an Excel Plugin, but are running into issues.

```
string fileUriPath = "pack://application:,,,/WpfVisualControls;Component/Resources/Localization-EN-US.xaml";
ResourceDictionary dict.Source = new Uri(fileUriPath);
```

When running within Excel, this throws the following exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: Invalid URI: Invalid port specified.
```

It runs fine under Visual Studio, so I am suspecting that something about the pack://application needs to be changed in Excel, I just don't know what that might be.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Further investigation shows that the Application.Current object is null, which is probably the cause of not being able to use the pack://application: path. However, declaring an Application object causes tons of issues, so that is probably not the final solution.

Comment: We know its solved if you accepted an answer. No need to edit the title :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to this after quite the goose chase:

```
string fileUriPath = "WpfVisualControls;Component/Resources/Localization-EN-US.xaml";
dict = Application.LoadComponent(new Uri(fileUriPath, UriKind.Relative)) as ResourceDictionary;
```

The Application.Current object being null caused the error, so using the static load component method resolved the URI for me.